# Creating vector layer as subset of another vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, filter, vector-layer, extract, qgsvectorlayer

With PyQGIS.I am trying to create a new vector layer by filtering another vector layer based on its attributes. Here is the code that I am using:

```py
fn = r"C:/path/file.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
features_layer = layer.getFeatures()

new_list = []
for feat in features_layer:
    attrs_layer = feat.attributes()
    if (boolean criteria for filtering on the attributes of the existing layer):
       new_list.append(attrs_layer)

file_path = r"C:/path/folder"
new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(file_path, '', "ogr")
provider = new_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field1", QVariant.Double)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field2", QVariant.Double)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field3", QVariant.Int)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field4", QVariant.Int)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field5", QVariant.Int)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("field6", QVariant.Double)])
new_layer.updateFields()

new_layer.startEditing()

for feat in new_layer.getFeatures():
    for i in new_list:
        feat['field1'] = i[0]
        feat['field2'] = i[1]
        feat['field3'] = i[2]
        feat['field4'] = i[3]
        feat['field5'] = i[4]
        feat['field6'] = i[5]
        new_layer.updateFeature(feat)
 
new_layer.commitChanges()

for field in new_layer.fields():
    print(field)
    print(field.name())
    print(field.type())
```

When I run this code, I see no errors but also no outputs. I was expecting the last for loop will return some properties of the new layer that I tried to create.

Comment: `QgsVectorLayer.updateFeature()` returns a boolean success indicator, best check that. I guess that you meant to use `feature` there, not `feat`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes there is a typo there it should be `feature` not `feat`. But I couldn't understand what you meant by checking the `QgsVectorLayer.updateFeature()` part.

Comment: Where do you use `new_list`? What is `region1`?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code with generic terms before posting here and forgot to change that line. `new_list` is `region1, I edited the post again.

Comment: ```feature_updated = new_layer.updateFeature(feat)
if feature_updated:
  # success
else:
  # error with your logic```

Comment: Açıkçası, ne yapmaya çalıştığınızı anlayamadım.

Comment: Hocam merhabalar, USGS tarafından Türkiye'deki depremler için paylaşılan sarsıntı haritalarını işlemeye çalışıyorum. Bölgede fazla sayıda yüksek büyüklükte deprem olduğu için birden fazla haritayla çalışıyorum ve amacım farklı depremlerden farklı şiddetlerde etkilenen alanları farklı gruplara ayırmak.

Sözün özü, bir depreme ait haritayı şiddet attribute'unu kullanarak filtrelemek ve bu filtrelenmiş halini başka bir layer haline getirmek istiyorum. Bunu da çok fazla kez yapacağım için otomatize etmek istemiştim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool to extract matching features from an input layer.

```py
input_file = r"C:/path/input.shp"
output_file = r"C:/path/output.shp"
filter = ' "intensity" > 4 ' # Edit criteria

output_file_path = processing.run("native:extractbyexpression",
                                 {'INPUT':input_file
                                  'EXPRESSION':filter,
                                  'OUTPUT':output_file})["OUTPUT"]

# Uncomment the lines below if you need to add the new layer to the project
# new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(output_file_path, "LAYER_NAME", "ogr")
# QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

Comment: [`runAndLoadResults()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) can also be useful ^_^

Comment: @Taras You are right. But I thought the OP could use it as an intermediate process.